# Different maven build profiles in a single hudson job

Tags: maven-2, hudson, profiles

I have multiple profiles in my build. One of them is a profile that is run on every checkin and does a standard build/test/findbugs/etc. I also have a nightly build profile that I run that runs a more in-depth build and captures more metrics. Right now I have two hudson jobs. Is there a way to combine these into a single job so I don't need to update both of them when something about the project changes? Ideally I could run one profile on the SCM changes and another profile nightly.

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, as these two jobs have some differences anyway:

- execution time (*at each commit* for the first one, *every night* for the second one);
- the Maven command is different: not the same goals (e.g. you can add `sonar:sonar` on the second job) or at least not the same profiles that are enabled.

Or maybe there is some "jobs synchronization" plugin?

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're right that it's not possible. But I'll keep an eye out for some plugins for that.